# Get the Firebase appId in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a mobile app. This project is divided into 2 entities (app), the first one is the CMS where I can upload and edit the Firestore database.
The second one, is the app itself where the user can login and see the content.

I need to restrict the access of the CMS and allow only specific user to be able to connect.
For that, I am writing a cloud function but I need to identity the appID to allow or not the user.

If the user try to access the CMS, I need to identify if is using the CMS APP and if does  I will check if his email is allowed.

I have been looking for days to find a way to identify the app within the cloud function but couldn't anything on Stack overflow or in the Firebase doc.

If anyone knows if this is possible and if not do you have any other suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't really optimal for what you want to achieve.  The app ID isn't really a "secure" piece of information for determining authorization.  It is public information and can be easily found by anyone using your application.

If you want to securely identify the user in a project, you should send an auth token to your backend, then validate that token using the Firebase Admin SDK.  This will verify that the user is signed in to your project.  The app ID doesn't matter at all in this case.

You will want to follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to understand how this works with examples.

Comment: Thanks for answer! but that option won't help to identify on which app the user is trying to logging to?

Comment: It shouldn't matter.  If you want to control what the individual user should be able to do, you should use some sort per-user authorization stored in a database or custom claims.  Decode the token, and look that up using their UID before you do anything for them.